# How to stop webpack from creating dist/main.js after upgrade to Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, phoenix-framework

I am using Webpack with Elixir/Phoenix. I recently upgraded to Webpack 5 from Webpack 4.

I think everything is working fine except that now for some reason a dist and main.js are always created at the project root `dist/main.js` when I run my tests. This file is mostly empty:

```
/*
 * ATTENTION: The "eval" devtool has been used (maybe by default in mode: "development").
 * This devtool is neither made for production nor for readable output files.
 * It uses "eval()" calls to create a separate source file in the browser devtools.
 * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)
 * or disable the default devtool with "devtool: false".
 * If you are looking for production-ready output files, see mode: "production" (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).
 */
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    
/******/    
/******/ })()
;
```

In my mix.exs I have the following. This is the line of code that creates the `dist/main.js`

```
  defp compile_assets(_) do
    Mix.shell().cmd("./assets/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode development",
      quiet: false
    )
  end
```

My webpack.config includes:

```
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: {
      'app': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js']),
      'marketing': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/marketing.js']),
      'admin': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/admin.js']),
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
    },
```

When I run this in IEx I get:

```
iex(1)> Mix.shell().cmd("./assets/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode development", quiet: false)
asset main.js 662 bytes [emitted] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/me/development/apps/my_app'
resolve './src' in '/Users/me/development/apps/my_app'
  No description file found in /Users/me/development/apps/my_app or above
  No description file found in /Users/me/development/apps/my_app or above
  no extension
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src doesn't exist
  .js
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src.js doesn't exist
  .json
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src.json doesn't exist
  .wasm
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src.wasm doesn't exist
  as directory
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src doesn't exist

webpack 5.50.0 compiled with 1 error in 50 ms
1
```

Since I have specified the entry I would assume it should be fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Showing entire webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = (webpackEnv, webpackOptions) => {

  const platform = process.env.PLATFORM
  if (platform == undefined) {
    throw "process.env.PLATFORM is undefined!"
  }
  dotEnvFile = `.env.${platform}`
  const mode = platform === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';
  const minimize = platform === 'production' ? true : false;
  const cache = platform === 'production' ? false : { type: 'filesystem' };
  const vueProdDevtools = platform === 'production' ? false : true;

  return {
    cache: cache,
    mode: mode,
    optimization: {
      minimize: minimize,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          parallel: true
        }),
        new CssMinimizerPlugin()
      ]
    },
    entry: {
      'app': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js']),
      'marketing': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/marketing.js']),
      'admin': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/admin.js']),
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'vue-loader',
              options: {
                compilerOptions: {
                  compatConfig: {
                    MODE: 2
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },      {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'vue-style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', dotEnvFile)
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/[name].css' }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({patterns:[{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }]}),
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: vueProdDevtools
      })
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue: '@vue/compat'
      },
      extensions: [ '*', '.js', '.vue', '.json' ],
    },
  }
};
```

Update 2:

Per the suggestion to turn filename into a function I updated it to:

```
    output: {
      filename: (pathData, assetInfo) => {
        console.log("******** pathData:", pathData)
        console.log("******** assetInfo:", assetInfo)

        return '[name].js'
      },
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
    }
```

The interesting bit is when I run

```
mix phx.server
```

The outputs are:

```
******** pathData: {
  hash: '449eeaf77670741a6887',
  runtime: 'app',
  chunk: Chunk {
    id: 'app',
    ids: [ 'app' ],
    debugId: 1000,
    name: 'app',
    idNameHints: SortableSet [Set] {
      _sortFn: undefined,
      _lastActiveSortFn: Symbol(not sorted),
      _cache: undefined,
      _cacheOrderIndependent: undefined
    },
    preventIntegration: false,
    filenameTemplate: undefined,
    _groups: SortableSet [Set] {
      [Entrypoint],
      _sortFn: [Function: compareChunkGroupsByIndex],
      _lastActiveSortFn: Symbol(not sorted),
      _cache: undefined,
      _cacheOrderIndependent: undefined
    },
    runtime: 'app',
    files: SetDeprecatedArray [Set] { '../css/app.css' },
    auxiliaryFiles: Set {},
    rendered: false,
    hash: '09da590258e85092531ee1a26f184db4',
    contentHash: [Object: null prototype] {
      'css/mini-extract': '4500f8bd1df6d9d548c3',
      javascript: 'a1a060a5ddfcebc58653'
    },
    renderedHash: '09da590258e85092531e',
    chunkReason: undefined,
    extraAsync: false
  },
  contentHashType: 'javascript'
}
******** assetInfo: {}
******** pathData: {
  hash: '449eeaf77670741a6887',
  runtime: 'marketing',
  chunk: Chunk {
    id: 'marketing',
    ids: [ 'marketing' ],
    debugId: 1001,
    name: 'marketing',
    idNameHints: SortableSet [Set] {
      _sortFn: undefined,
      _lastActiveSortFn: Symbol(not sorted),
      _cache: undefined,
      _cacheOrderIndependent: undefined
    },
    preventIntegration: false,
    filenameTemplate: undefined,
    _groups: SortableSet [Set] {
      [Entrypoint],
      _sortFn: [Function: compareChunkGroupsByIndex],
      _lastActiveSortFn: Symbol(not sorted),
      _cache: undefined,
      _cacheOrderIndependent: undefined
    },
    runtime: 'marketing',
    files: SetDeprecatedArray [Set] { '../css/marketing.css' },
    auxiliaryFiles: Set {},
    rendered: false,
    hash: 'e11f89b04d9e2d62877069c780bfd99c',
    contentHash: [Object: null prototype] {
      'css/mini-extract': '1218451d2cf9d01e4c35',
      javascript: '0bf8255fc0482a761bba'
    },
    renderedHash: 'e11f89b04d9e2d628770',
    chunkReason: undefined,
    extraAsync: false
  },
  contentHashType: 'javascript'
}
******** assetInfo: {}
******** pathData: {
  hash: '449eeaf77670741a6887',
  runtime: 'admin',
  chunk: Chunk {
    id: 'admin',
    ids: [ 'admin' ],
    debugId: 1002,
    name: 'admin',
    idNameHints: SortableSet [Set] {
      _sortFn: undefined,
      _lastActiveSortFn: Symbol(not sorted),
      _cache: undefined,
      _cacheOrderIndependent: undefined
    },
    preventIntegration: false,
    filenameTemplate: undefined,
    _groups: SortableSet [Set] {
      [Entrypoint],
      _sortFn: [Function: compareChunkGroupsByIndex],
      _lastActiveSortFn: Symbol(not sorted),
      _cache: undefined,
      _cacheOrderIndependent: undefined
    },
    runtime: 'admin',
    files: SetDeprecatedArray [Set] { '../css/admin.css' },
    auxiliaryFiles: Set {},
    rendered: false,
    hash: '6a55d7e6d1cc37be6087e1c464285cc2',
    contentHash: [Object: null prototype] {
      'css/mini-extract': '613df220ea4099b5fbf5',
      javascript: '90a7803cefe86244fd07'
    },
    renderedHash: '6a55d7e6d1cc37be6087',
    chunkReason: undefined,
    extraAsync: false
  },
  contentHashType: 'javascript'
}
******** assetInfo: {}
```

So, I see that it run one time for each entry point (makes sense). However, when in IEx and I do:

```
Interactive Elixir (1.12.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Mix.shell().cmd("./assets/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode development", quiet: false)
asset main.js 662 bytes [compared for emit] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/me/development/apps/my_app'
resolve './src' in '/Users/me/development/apps/my_app'
  No description file found in /Users/me/development/apps/my_app or above
  No description file found in /Users/me/development/apps/my_app or above
  no extension
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src doesn't exist
  .js
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src.js doesn't exist
  .json
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src.json doesn't exist
  .wasm
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src.wasm doesn't exist
  as directory
    /Users/me/development/apps/my_app/src doesn't exist

webpack 5.51.1 compiled with 1 error in 47 ms
1
```

So the `console.log` command isn't printing in IEx. Could that be related? Could be be that the command the test code is running, the one in IEx, is running a "different" webpack command? Is it perhaps not finding the webpack.config?

Comment: Can you share your entire webpack configuration? It's likely you returned something empty in the webpack config file.

Comment: @Wenbo I added the entire webpack.config.js

Comment: How about change the `filename` under `output` as a function and then set a breakpoint in the function to diagnose. The function can be like 
```
filename: (path) => {
console.log("**** path: ",path, " name: ", [name]);
    },
```

Comment: @Wenbo great suggestion. I updated the question with the output. Does that give you any ideas?

Comment: @Wenbo Can you answer this question by suggesting something along the lines of the issue being related to the `compile_assets` function because the issue only comes up for that scenario. The error message implies that webpack is not finding the webpack config. There may be something wrong in `./assets/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`. I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: as you doubted, possibly it didn't load your webpack config because from the log you post, it didn't show the lines you added. To confirm, can you set breakpoint at the beginning of the webpack config to see if the bp triggers. Or simply specify the config by `webpack --config xxx.js`. And `webpack --config xxx.js --stats verbose` may help to see the reason.

Comment: @Wenbo Thank you. How can I award you the bounty? You'd have to answer with your suggestion to debug and implying that the config isn't loading.

Thank you again!

Comment: Have you fixed by specifying the configuration? Or by these suggestions you got the reason? If so, then I answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason dist/main.js is created is because when webpack is run it is unable to find a webpack.config.js and so dist/main.js is a default behavior.

I discovered this when I updated the `filename` to be a function. In it I then called `console.log("test")` and expected to see it in IEx. The console log never printed out.

I then ran the regular `mix phx.server` and I did get the new output.

In `dev.exs` there's:

```
    watchers: [
      node: [
        "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
        "--mode",
        "development",
        "--progress",
        "--watch",
        "--watch-options-stdin",
        cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)
      ]
    ]
```

This all looks as expected but with a different implementation. (It is using `cd: Path.expand` but I'm only noticing this now.)

So, why is one not working while the other is fine?

When taking a closer look at

```
  defp compile_assets(_) do
    Mix.shell().cmd("./assets/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode development",
      quiet: false
    )
  end
```

I decided to see where I got this from (which was from the Wallaby documentation)

I went back to the documentation and noticed it had changed.

Here is the change:
https://github.com/elixir-wallaby/wallaby/commit/834bdb726228349f800837e470a0c77cd2f4a6bd

Now the code should be:

```
  defp compile_assets(_) do
    Mix.shell().cmd("cd assets && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode development",
      quiet: true
    )
```

I don't know why we'd need to cd into assets vs what we had before, but now it works.